# Как в С# получить ответ от метода из Objective-C

Tags: c#, objective-c

Создаю игру в *Unity3D*, есть модуль на *Objective-C*, который возвращает *bool*

```
    + (BOOL)userRatedApp{
         if (forceUnlock){
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:SaveKey];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            return YES;


           }
    #else
    #endif
    BOOL rateNeed = NO;
    if (rateNeed) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:SaveKey];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }

    return rateNeed;
    }
```

как мне вызвать этот метод в С# и получить состояние Bool-a.

Comment: Вангую, без пайпов не обойтись

Comment: может есть какая то инфа где описано как что то подобное делается ?

Comment: Насчет objective-c не подскажу, но базовый пример на C# можно [посмотреть тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806153/example-of-named-pipes)